# How to apply gradient color for an image using createjs?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

How to apply gradient fill using createjs? Below is the code for creating loading the image and i have changed the color using color filter but i want to apply the gradient color

```
 let rightContainer = new createjs.Container();
                let rightMain = new window.createjs.Bitmap(rightImage);
                // leftMain.scaleX = 800 / leftMain.image.width;
                rightMain.scaleY = 800 / rightMain.image.height;
                rightContainer.addChild(rightMain);
                rightMain.x = 300;
                rightMain.y = 0;
                this.layerImage = rightMain.clone();
                this.layerImage.alpha = 0.15;
                rightContainer.addChild(this.layerImage);
                rightMain.filters = [new window.createjs.ColorFilter(0, 0, 0, 1, 117, 111, 115, 0)];
                rightContainer.main = rightMain;
                rightMain.cache(0, 0, rightMain.image.width, rightMain.image.height);
                rightContainer.visible = false;
                this.stage.addChild(rightContainer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? Apply a gradient on the color filtered image?

An approach you could use is:

1. Draw a box with a gradient in it
2. Cache it so it can be used as an AlphaMaskFilter
3. Apply it to the bitmap as a filter
4. Cache the bitmap to apply the filter.

I made an demo to show how it would work:
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/uog3hkpd/2/

```
// Draw a gradient in a shape:
s.graphics.lf(["#000", "rgba(0,0,0,0)"], [0, 0], 0,0,960,0);

// Cache the shape
s.cache(0,0,960,400);

// Add the alphamaskfilter + a color adjustment for fun
var col = new createjs.ColorMatrix().adjustHue(180);
bmp.filters = [
    new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(s.cacheCanvas), 
    new createjs.ColorMatrixFilter(col)
];

// Cache it to apply filters
bmp.cache(0,0,960,400);
```

The demo does a few other things, such as

- Adding a second bmp underneath that is not filtered
- Animating the ratio of the gradient (requires a re-cache)

I hope that helps you with your question. If you have any specific code or examples you need help with, please feel free to clarify.

Cheers,